# MySQL update Script to my clients

Tags: mysql

We recently made an update to one of our main web based systems.
Some of our clients use  a desktop based system with a MySQL database to send payments and other info to our main web based system.

The issue is that i want to add a new field in one of their tables in their database without  asking them to manually add the field, something i can send them to run over an e-mail or like a batch script or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Write the SQL code that will add the new field in one of the table. Test it thoroughly and make sure the SQL code is ok.
2. Write an application that will run the SQL to update the clients' database
3. Publish the application and notify your clients that it is an update to keep the software good.

It is more advisable to include a self-updating component to your clients' desktop application so that in future if an update is required, you can simply push it out via the updater.

Comment: You should probably make sure there is rollback functionality in there too.